# ValueError: Number of priors must match number of classes

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I want to compile my python3 code on ubuntu, and also want to know about the problem, such that i can handle that in future.

It seems there is some problem with the imported library function.

```
## sample code
1  import numpy as np
2  x = np.array([[-1,-1],[-2,-1],[-3,-2],[1,1],[2,1],[3,2]])
3  y = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2])
4  from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
5  clf = GaussianNB(x, y)
6  clf = clf.fit(x,y) ###showing error on compiling
7  print(clf.predict([[-2,1]]))



## output shown

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "naive.py", line 7, in <module>
    clf = clf.fit(x,y)
  File "/home/abhihsek/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
   packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 192, in fit
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/home/abhihsek/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 371, in _partial_fit
    raise ValueError('Number of priors must match number of'
ValueError: Number of priors must match number of classes.



## code of library function  line 192
190  X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
191          return self._partial_fit(X, y, np.unique(y), 
_refit=True,
192  

                                 sample_weight=sample_weight)

## code of library function   line 371
369  # Check that the provide prior match the number of classes
370                  if len(priors) != n_classes:
371                      raise ValueError('Number of priors must 
match 
  number of'
372                                       ' classes.')
373                # Check that the sum is 1
```

Comment: Do `clf = GaussianNB()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Suvan Pandey mentioned, then the code won't give any error when writing `clf = GaussianNB()` instead of `clf = GaussianNB(x, y)`.

If we look at the GaussianNB class then the `__init__()` can take these parameters:

```
    def __init__(self, priors=None, var_smoothing=1e-9): # <-- these have a default value
        self.priors = priors
        self.var_smoothing = var_smoothing
```

The documentation about the two parameters:

> **priors** – Prior probabilities of the classes. If specified the priors are not adjusted according to the data.
>   **var_smoothing** – Portion of the largest variance of all features that is added to variances for calculation stability.

As your `x` and `y` variables both return an array object then they don't fit the parameters of the `__init__(...)`.